# Can I display DIV gallery on background?

Tags: html, css, nivo-slider

I'm currently using nivo-slider here the problem is, I want the displayed pictures in a background. I have position:absolute but its not working. The gallery itself is in top position and all other divs are behind it. 
Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use css property z-index for this

Use lower z-index for the element you want to appear on the back like

z-index:1

and use higher z-index for the elements you want to appear on top

z-index:10

Answer (score 0):

Set a higher z-index on the elements you wont to show on top of the slideshow. For full cross browser support make sure that the element is placed after the slideshow in the code.

Answer (score 0):

add z-index to the slideshow element , while the element to be displayed in background leave it without z-index.
for example

> .slideshow {  z-index: 10;}